# Android WebView URL problems

Tags: android, url, webview

I have android app hosting a web site in WebView. It works fine, but has one issue. Whenever users search in Google and click on page of this site, the application is opening not at that page but on home page of the web site.
For example: they click on www.example.com/blog - WebView app is open but it shows homepage, not blog.
Links (navigation) works fine inside of application when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

try these code

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
return false;
}
});
```

when you click on any link on webview then view.loadurl() method again load new url.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.